# Compiling from Sublime Text (Windows 10): g++: command not found

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I have created a **C++14.sublime-build** file from `tools>Build System>New Build System`.
The code that I placed inside is:

```json
{
 
 "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"],
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
 "variants":
 [
   {
     "name": "Run",
     "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
   }
 ]
}
```

But whenever I select `C++14` from `tools> Build System`, an error occurs saying `/bin/bash: g++: command not found`

**Note: The program compiles and works properly when I select C++ Single File in tools>Build System.**

Please help!

Comment: "g++: command not found" - So install the compiler, gcc/g++ . Sublime is just a text editor. It's not your compiler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the OP states right in the question that when using another C++ build system, *"The program compiles and works properly"*. So, gcc/g++ is clearly already installed and functional...

Comment: is there some reason you're trying to invoke bash to get it to run the command instead of just using `shell_cmd`, which does the same thing? On Linux, `shell_cmd` does what you're doing; on MacOS it also provides `-l` to make sure that the environment is set up correctly. So if you're on MacOS, that might solve your issue

Comment: As an added note, your `Run` variant is not appropriately named (which is harmless but confusing). Both builds will always compile and run, the only difference is that the top level build also includes `-Wall`. All else being equal, you may be better off creating a build based on the default and not from random advice on the internet, which is frequently incorrect or misleading in my experience helping people with build problems.

Comment: @OdatNurd I am using windows. How to fix the problem?

Comment: Are you using WSL for this, or just MinGW?

Comment: @OdatNurd just MinGW

Comment: It's probably complaining about you trying to use `bash`; as I mentioned above, is there some reason you're trying to use `bash` here?